# HP Victus: USB ports slowly stopped working at all

Tags: ubuntu, usb, laptop, windows-11, hp

I've been using HP Victus 16-d0065ur (5B864EA) for 1,5 years.

Two weeks ago my mouse (with cable) just stopped working on this laptop -> I tried to insert in to "regular" desktop PC -> mouse worked without any problem

Then I tried the another mouse:  bluetooth mouse on this laptop -> it was working for 1 weeks and then... well... also stopped working!

I was thinking it was problem with win11, but I have Ubuntu as second OS on my laptop (dual boot mode) -> no any USB device (include mouses) does not work either on Ubuntu! - but worked perfectly before!

Both USB ports stopped working in both OS-es!

How it is possible?

if there was a electric short circuit, then the USB ports would burn right away, But they **gradually** "died", so it was not "circuit"?

On restart I tried to run HP Assistant tool, it reported *" HP USB port check has identified a citical failure in your system that requires repair"*

Could you please provide some ideas what to do with that?

In win11 "Device Manager" both ports are visible.

Comment: This seems like a hardware problem. I suggest taking it to a professional technician for checkup.